# ibus 1.4.1 doesn't work with Opera 12

Tags: 12.04, qt, ibus, opera

Environment:
Ubuntu 12.04
Opera 12
ibus 1.4.1

I've installed ibus-qt and add the two lines below in /usr/bin/opera, but it makes no difference:

```
QT_IM_MODULE=xim
XMODIFIERS="@im=ibus"
```

As some say that QT has been deprecated in Opera, so I've also added `GTK_IM_MODULE=xim` in Opera, but still no difference.

Am I missing something or we just can't use ibus in Opera 12?

Answer (score 1):

OK,now I figure it out...
It turns out that I need to start `ibus` with parameter `-x` so that XIM starts up.
I added these lines to ~/.bashrc:

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
export XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
export XIM=ibus
export QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
export XIM_ARGS="ibus-daemon -d -x"
```

Then I modified the startup applications, `ibus-daemon -dxr`
The last step, modify the `/usr/bin/opera`, add

```
GTK_IM_MODULE=xim
QT_IM_MODULE=xim
XMODIFIERS="@im=ibus"
```

It works like a charm... This might be a piece of cake for many users but I think it can help a lot of newbies like me:)